# Algorithm for generating a list of recurring pairs

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinatorics

> Given a text file in the format below, each line is a list of up to 50
>   names. Write a program produces a list of pairs of names which appear
>   together in at least fifty different lists.
>
> ```
> Tyra,Miranda,Naomi,Adriana,Kate,Elle,Heidi
> Daniela,Miranda,Irina,Alessandra,Gisele,Adriana
> ```
>
> In the above sample, Miranda and Adriana appear together twice, but
>   every other pair appears only once. It should return
>   "Miranda,Adriana\n". An approximate solution may be returned with
>   lists which appear at least 50 times with high probability.

I was thinking of the following solution:

1. Generate a `Map <Pair,Integer>` pairToCountMap, after reading through the file.
2. Iterate through the map, and print those with counts >= 50

Is there a better way to do this?  The file could be very large, and I'm not sure what is meant by the approximate solution.  Any links or resources would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's assume that names are limited in length, so operations on them are constant time.

Your answer should be acceptable if it fits in memory.  If you have `N` lines with `m` names each, your solution should take `O(N*m*m)` to complete.

If that data set doesn't fit in memory, you can write the pairs to a file, sort that file using a merge sort, then scan through to count pairs.  The running time of this is `O(N*m*log(N*m))`, but due to details about speed of disk access will run much faster in practice.

If you have a distributed cluster, then you could use a MapReduce.  It would run very similarly to the last solution.

As for the statistics approach, my guess is that they mean running through the list of files to find the frequency of each name, and the number of lines with different numbers of names in them.  If we assume that each line is a random assortment of names, using statistics we can estimate how many intersections there are between any pair of common names.  This will be roughly linear in the length of the file.

Comment: what do you mean by 'write the pairs to a file', does that mean we have to write `m^2` items per input line?

Comment: @unkulunkulu Exactly.  Always write the pair of names sorted.

Comment: @btilly I'm having trouble understanding the statistics approach. Can you point me to some links or a Wikipedia topic? Thx.

Comment: @project.zylon How difficult statistics is depends on how sophisticated you want to be.  The easiest case is when the lists are random and can repeat names.  In that case if word A has proportion `p` of the words, and word B has proportion `q`, then in a list of `i` words the probability that both appear is `(1-q)^i + (1-p)^i - (1 - p - q)^i`.  Sum up the probabilities over all lists in which they might occur, and you have the expected number of pairs they might be in.  Beyond that simplified case, it is all a question of how accurate you need your heuristic to be.

Comment: An improved heuristic for the case without repetition where no word takes up a large proportion of all words is that the probability that both appear in a list of length `i` is `i*i*p*q`.  This estimate is not exact, but may be close enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can for each name obtain the list of the line numbers where it appears (use a hashtable to store the names), then for every pair of names get the size of the intersection of the corresponding line indices (in the case of two increasing sequences this is linear time).
Say the length of a name is limited by a constant. So if you have `N` names and `M` lines, then building the list is like `O(MN)` and the final stage is `O(N^2 M)`.

Comment: +1, but I think you just mean "intersection" instead of "greatest common subsequence" (which works but is a more general problem).  You would keep the line lists in sorted order and use a list merge to find this intersection.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I was just back from solving one greatest common subsequence problem, so my mind caught me, intersection is just plain logic for this problem, agree with you.

Comment: Your running time is no better than his in the best case, and is substantially slower in the case where there are a lot of pairs of names that do not appear on any line in common.